# Produce CSV from JSON object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON Object like so that I am trying to produce a CSV from

```
{
    "football": {
        "count": 2109,
        "emailed": 0,
        "optin": 2109,
    },
    "tennis": {
        "count": 61114,
        "emailed": 11111,
        "optin": 555,
    }
}
```

However, the fields titles have to be different

What I am after is essentially something like this

```
Sport, Total, Emails Sent, No Opt Ins,
football, 2109, 0, 2109,
tennis, 61114, 11111, 555
```

I am tried using packages but can't seem to get it working, as such, then tried doing it myself

```
const fields = ['Sport', 'Total', 'Emails Sent', 'No Opt Ins'];
```

I wrapped my JSON in an array so I could use map

```
try {
  const replacer = (key, value) => (value === null ? '' : value);
  const csv = [
    fields.join(','),
    ...dataReduced.map((row) => fields.map((fieldName) => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(',')),
  ].join('\r\n');
  console.log(csv);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Obviously that wont work because the field names do not match the Object names.  How can I produce a CSV output in the way described above?

Thanks

Comment: I'd convert to an array of objects ... using `array = Object.entries(obj).map(([sport, value]) => ({sport, ...value}));` ... once you have an array of objects, it should be simple

Answer (score 2):

Since the row is an object literal, the keys may not necessarily be sorted, so the `map` here is not enough, there should be a mapper for columns, something like this:

```js
const row = {
    "football": {
        "count": 2109,
        "emailed": 0,
        "optin": 2109,
    },
    "tennis": {
        "count": 61114,
        "emailed": 11111,
        "optin": 555,
    }
};

const head = {
  football: {id: 0, name: 'Sport'},
  count: {id: 1, name: 'Total'},
  emailed: {id: 2, name: 'Emails Sent'},
  optin: {id: 3, name: 'No Opt Ins'}
};

const csv = [Object.values(head).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
  .map(value => value.name).join()];

Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  const line = [key];
  Object.entries(value).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    line[head[key].id] = value;
  });
  csv.push(line.join());
});

console.log(csv.join('\n'));
```

Comment: Thank you - I seem to be having an issue with ids.  I have created a Fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/3h2cr4yq/ Thanks

Comment: You should define all the row header names in the `head` object.

Comment: What happens if I do not know the names?  This object is coming from somewhere else

Comment: Well, own and not own, these are very different situations that needs different approaches.